# HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs() is not implemented

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.8

I am getting an error when trying to run:

```
                string PicType = File.ContentType;
                var ItemFileGUID_Temp = Guid.NewGuid();
                string TempPath = $"{ItemFileUp.ItemFileUpPath}{ItemFileGUID_Temp}{ItemFileExt}";
                File.SaveAs(TempPath);
```

File is type: `HttpPostedFileBase`

And TempPath results in a physical path: `"E:\\sitextras\\CIL\\_2016\\ImagesCust\\imagesdb\\project\\5ac8ef27-67ff-4f77-9b0e-5efa94b82f0c.png"`

But when it hits the "SaveAs(TempPath)" line it throws the following error:

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

My function must take in a HttpPostedFileBase and I haven't seen anyone else with the issue. The actual .NET page says the same thing about the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase.saveas?view=netframework-4.8.1

So how do I implement this function? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: What is the actual runtime type of `File`? Use the debugger. `HttpPostedFileBase` is the abstract base type, so it cannot be the real type. I guess the real type has not implemented this method.

Comment: Documentation you provided says "When __overridden in a derived class__, saves the contents of an uploaded file." You should implement your own save method for this to work.